# Loading Rails into an iRuby Jupyter notebook for deployment on AWS ECS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jupyter-notebook, capistrano3, rails-console, iruby

My end goal is to provide a Jupyter Notebook that can run any code that I would normally run from a Rails console, so that our data scientists can make notebooks using directly the models from our existing Rails app, and easily draw/refresh some graphs based on the models.

I'm using the iRuby gem and help sections to successfully make a docker image that would be able to load our Rails environment.

Assuming we have a Rails project/console as a github project with a git repository, **how can I setup jupyter with iRuby AND load the code from our main Rails application ?**

My end goal is to build a docker image that I could easily deploy on AWS ECS to provide a microservice with a "Jupyter Rails console". Once I have the docker image running the "Jupyter Rails console", deploying on ECS should be a piece of cake

I am using the sciruby Dockerfile from https://hub.docker.com/r/minad/sciruby-notebooks/dockerfile. What should I do to load the code from our Rails project ?

*Note : I am also using Capistrano, and it turns out I had previously found a way to "deploy" our Rails code inside a container using Capistrano, in case this may help to draft a solution*